# change xmlns value per element in xmlns

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to ask how xmlns attribute can be added to an element on xsd.

The output should be something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<asn>
    <itemcode id="ITM0002212">
        <serialno xmlns="1231123321231600000">
            <msn/>
            <msisdn>123456789</msisdn>
        </serialno>             
        <serialno xmlns="1231123321231700000">
            <msn/>
            <msisdn>123456788</msisdn>
        </serialno>
        <serialno xmlns="1231123321231800000">
            <msn/>
            <msisdn>123456787</msisdn>
        </serialno>
        <serialno xmlns="1231123321231900000">
            <msn/>
            <msisdn>123456786</msisdn>
        </serialno>
    </itemcode>
</asn>
```

I tried to use the following xsd below but the application does not allow the attribute xmlns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="asn">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="itemcode">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="serialno">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <element name="nac" type="xs:string" />
                                    <element name="msisdn" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <attribute name="xmlns" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

`xmlns` attributes are not really attributes. They are resolved by the XML parser to declare a default namespace in which `serialno`, `msn` and `msisdn` live. Hence, XML Schema does not actually see them in the form of attributes. In general, XML forbids and reserves attribute names that begin with `xml` in any combination of case.

However, looking at the XML document provided, the values associated with `xmlns` do not look like URI references, and each `serialno` has its own `xmlns` value, which is uncommon: one would have to provide a separate schema file for each one of these namespaces. This may point out that these are or should be `id` fields or custom fields rather than `xmlns` fields.

Comment: Hi, it may be true that the xmlns in the serialno is an id value. It's just that the output that I need should be xmlns . I did try to change the attribute name from `xmlns` to `xmlns1` (for testing) and the application accepted (ms excel source). the data though comes from an excel spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Ryan, I'm afraid this looks like an unusual at best, non-standard at worst, usage of the `xmlns` attribute. Is there any documentation that explains the specifics of your usecase? It is expected that `xmlns1` would not be rejected by the application. The idea of reserving these names is that (even if it is now becoming unlikely) the W3C reserves itself the right in the future to specify semantics for `xmlns1` or others, like it did for `xmlns`, which may break any existing uses.

Comment: very unusual indeed. I really can't provide you with details of the use case though other than I was given a task of creating a xml with given a format similar to the xml output on my question. The data will come from an excel file so I tried to use the export to xml function of excel by creating XSD. I'm really new to xsd so I was wondering if anyone had encountered my situation and came up with a solution for xsd. Thanks